# Is it possible to use ngFor in select tags in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

So, I have a unique use case, where I have to display multiple select tags which have multiple options (each).
So, the data structure is an array of an array of objects.

```html
<div class="form-group row" *ngIf="myData">
  <select [(ngModel)]="singleData" *ngFor="let singleSelectGroup of myData; let i=index" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="mySelectGroup">
    <option *ngFor="let singleOptionGroup of singleSelectGroup" [ngValue]="singleTag">{{singleOption.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Now, obviously this doesn't work, each time I select an option from a dropdown, any other option selected would go blank since there is a single `ngModel`.
Is there a way to tackle such a use case in angular?
Also, any option tag with a default selected and disabled attribute would go blank as well.
Any help or push in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a Stackblitz?

Comment: Sounds like you may need to use a Form Array: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array instead, and bind `ngModel` to `array[i]`.

Here's a basic example which you can customise to fit your needs:

```js
export class MyComponent {
  allData = [];
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group row" *ngIf="myData">
  <select [(ngModel)]="allData[i]" *ngFor="let singleSelectGroup of myData; let i=index" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="mySelectGroup">
    <option *ngFor="let singleOptionGroup of singleSelectGroup" [ngValue]="singleTag">{{singleOption.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```